# How to monitor Password Filter dll loading at system boot ?

Tags: c, windows, debugging, dll, remote-debugging

I have custom `Password filter` dll written in C. This dll will be used by `lsass` process. This dll gets loaded at the time of system startup. For some reason dll not getting loaded and machine crashes. I want to know is there any way to monitor this dll loading and why m/c is crashing. Can we use remote debugger of  Visual studio ? I dont want to add code in dll for writing `Eventlog`.

Comment: If you don't want add eventlog functionality, then implement custom debug log file logging.When you solve it, just remove it...

Comment: @rkosegi: I tried this approach, but don't know why even that log file doesn't get created. I though this might be because of write permissions,but no other sample applications are able to create file at same locatuion.

Comment: did you try "well writable" location like %TEMP% or dedicated D: drive with Full Access for Everyone?

Comment: @rkosegi: yes i have tried such locations

Comment: this sounds like your DLL never take in place, so can not log anything anywhere.If "machine crashes", system should anyway something log to eventlog.Can you share this info with us? You may consider enabling automatic application minudumps and anaylze them offline http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315263

Comment: after restoring m/c ,i am not getting anything related to m/c crash in Eventlogs

Comment: Random thought: are you sure the DLL has the correct architecture?  If the DLL is 32-bit and Windows is 64-bit, you're going to get a crash.  Also check that the registry entry has the correct name for the DLL (without the .dll extension) and that the DLL is in the system32 folder.

Comment: @Harry Johnston:Actually my dll is password filter. dll creats log file when it gets loaded successfully. my dll get loaded successfully, when i provide log file path to some other location except(c:\ or d:\ ). This log file path value is stored in registry. Dll reads this registry value at time of loading. So if log file path  is, For example "c:\user\document" then Dll gets loaded. But if log file path is "c:\" or "d:\" or any wrong path then dll doesn't  get loaded and m/c crashes. c:\ and d:\ drive have full write permission to all user.

Comment: Try writing a simple test program to load and initialize your DLL.  See whether the log file is successfully created or not.  If not, you can run the test program in a debugger to see what's going wrong.